# What seems to be the error/mistake in this line of code that I added to my crontab configuration file?

Tags: cron

```
    0 0 * * 6 /usr/sbin/chkrootkit 2>&1 | mail -s "chkrootkit Reports of my server"  myemail@example.com
```

I expected an email to be sent to me once per week but instead nothing has been sent. What did I do wrong?

Comment: And are there any error messages indicating the problem?

Comment: No there are no errors indicating the problem @GeorgeUdosen. What can I do to diagnose the issue?

Comment: Mail and cron can be tricky. What have you done to set it up? Does the mail part of the job work from the command line command as your user? Can you run the job as your user by specifying that in the crontab line for the job? You may be running as the job as root so mail may need to be configured for that. Try turning the job into a shell script and direct the output of each line to a text file.

Comment: Mail does run in the terminal, however nothing is being sent to my email. I did a "whereis mail" command which yielded: mail: /usr/bin/mail.mailutils /usr/bin/mail /usr/share/man/man1/mail.1.gz. I also ran mail using sudo and it ran but yielded no errors. The same issue was experienced i.e no email was sent to my email address.